# Mongoose if empty string "" use default

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I have in my Schema:

```
image: {
        type: String,
        default: "http://via.placeholder.com/250x200"
},
```

So when user doesn't enter anything in field "image", it returns "". How do I validate that empty string "" should go to default as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to handle this in Mongoose itself, your best bet is to handle this in the code that instantiates the model before passing that object into the model's constructor.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
const objFromUser = { 'test' : '', 'test2' : 'test2' }
if (!objFromUser.test) delete objFromUser.test
const model = new MyModel(objFromUser)
```